# Cookie management for Salesforce Experience Sites

Tags: community, customer-community, customer-portal, cookies, experience-builder-page

See https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_cookies.htm&type=5.

Salesforce says it doesn’t currently provide functionality for end-user cookie consent management in Experience Builder sites, but the platform is compatible with many existing third-party solutions.

We'd like to use One Trust, but embedding javascript on the experience site is not permitted.

My question is - how are others approaching end-user cookie management for third-party solutions?

Comment: We are using this on our experience site. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000G11jcUAB

Comment: Thanks manjit5190 - we considered using the Salesforce Labs app exchange app but as we have another website that will link to our experience site, we didn't want users to have to accept cookies twice. We're therefore hoping to use a cookie management platform and integrate it with Salesforce.